# How do I customize Joomla 2.5 contact component?

Tags: php, components, joomla2.5

I'm trying to setup an alternative layout for the contact component in Joomla 2.5 but my template doesn't seem to be used when the page loads. Here's how I set it up using the documentation found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

```
/templates/MyTemplate/html/com_contact/contact/alternativelayout.php
```

Then on the administrator view in my contact component under "Display Options" I have selected alternativeLayout as my "Alternative Layout" and made modifications to the file (even deleted all the code in it) but it seems as if the default layout is always loaded.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include in your

```
templates/YourTemplate/
```

a file

```
templateDetails.xml
```

which describe your template and include your folders and files (an exmample from beez5 default template)

```
<files>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>html</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>javascript</folder>
    <folder>fonts</folder>
    <folder>language</folder>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>index.php</filename>
    ...
    ...
</files>
```

Check for this files in other template root folders.

Comment: I DO have that for my template, my question was using an alternative layout for a component (contact component to be specific). I followed the guide in the link but Joomla seems to use the default even when the alternative is selected.
Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to solve this as follows:

1. set alternativelayout.php file name to the original name:

   /templates/MyTemplate/html/com_contact/contact/default.php
2. set "Contact"->"Display options"->"Alternative Layout" to "Use Global"

it works for me.